# How do I change owner/permissions of auto mount on an embedded linaro based linux

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

I have an ARM based embedded system that when it auto mounts a USB drive it mounts it:

```
drwx------ 6 linaro linaro 2048 Jan 1 1970 PENDRIVE
```

I need to change the permissions and possibly thew owner of the drive automatically as it is mounted by automount.

My system is:

> Linux Marsmpd 3.0.36-t3+ #19 PREEMPT Mon Aug 6 12:10:13 EST 2012 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

How do I accomplish this?

Also is there a way to run a script automatically when it is automounted?

Comment: What file system is on the usb drive ? Do you have any idea how it is automounting ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write a script that checks to see if it's mounted and then unmount it (`umount /the/mount/point`), and then re-mount it as you want. This will likely be much easier then trying to figure out what's doing the mounting.

#### Example

1. Use the output of the `mount`, grep'ing for the mount you want to re-mount
2. umount /path/to/mount
3. mount  /path/to/dev /path/to/new/mount
4. run your script

You can make this part of the system boot by adding this to `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Find the UUID of your device:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```
2. Umount your USB Drive:

   ```
   umount /mnt/mountpoint
   ```
3. Remount it with the UUID option:

   ```
   mount /dev/whateverdevice /mnt/mountpoint -U <UUID of your USB Drive> -o rw
   ```
4. Run your chown command:

   ```
   chown user.user /mnt/mountpoint -R
   ```

Some more information here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ARM but possibly you can use udev rules to do this automatically. for example, see this here:
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Linux_udev_USB_Device_Permissions_Configuration

and http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gizmod/index.php?title=HOWTO_-_Setting_Input_Device_Permissions_-_Creating_a_udev_Rule